# linux + visudo + how to remove sub folder and sub files

Tags: linux, sudoedit

I edit in visudo the following , in order to enable user to remove any folder or file under  **/var/log/http**/ include sun folder

```
 UserT ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: sudoedit /var/log/http/*
```

user can remove file or folder under /var/log/http/*

but not sub folders/files unde /var/log/http/ , as /var/log/http/hT/*

I also edit the visudo with

```
UserT ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/rm -r /var/log/http/hT/*
```

and I do

```
sudo rm -r /var/log/http/hT/GG/file.txt

[sudo] password for UserT:
Sorry, user UserT is not allowed to execute '/bin/rm -r file' as root on
```

what need to fix here in order to remove also the sub folders/files under **/var/log/http/../../../../**

Answer (score -1):

This is possible by changing the user permission for `/var/log/http/hT` directory.